# Force UWP app to run always with 100% screen scale factor

Tags: layout, uwp, screen, scale

My UWP application layout is working as expected when screen scale is 100%. But when I change it from "Display Settings > Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to any value larger than 100% like 125% or 150% the layout is damaged.

So I need to know how to force it run always on 100% scale factor, even if use changed it from Display Settings.

This is available and easy in WPF, but I need to do the same in UWP windows apps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should fix your Layout to be able to scale correctly instead of trying to force a 100% scale factor. Some devices (e.g. Surface Book) use a scale factor of 200% as default, so your application would be scaled wrong if you force it to 100%. Use VisualStates to change the layout when resized/scaled.

Comment: What do you intend by "would be scaled wrong if you force it to 100%" ? 
And can you provide a simple example please :)

Comment: [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2016/08/16/display-scaling-changes-for-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/) is a good read about scaling in windows 10. Look at [this image](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/08/Picture210.png) from the blog post to see what happens when you don't scale your application. Also read [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/01/make-your-app-look-great-on-any-size-screen-or-window-10-by-10/#rC84iq4mJB1qSeyg.97) to get an idea about Visual States.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas